# Webcam not working on Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb, webcam

I have the Razer Kiyo Pro webcam that works fine on a Windows 10 computer, but does not work on my Xubuntu laptop.

Here is the dmesg output from when I connect the camera to my laptop:

```
[  232.440554] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  232.465286] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1532, idProduct=0e05, bcdDevice= 8.21
[  232.465293] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  232.465295] usb 2-1: Product: Razer Kiyo Pro
[  232.465297] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Razer Inc
[  232.468819] usb 2-1: Found UVC 1.00 device Razer Kiyo Pro (1532:0e05)
[  232.470407] uvcvideo 2-1:1.1: Failed to set UVC probe control : -32 (exp. 26).
[  232.471069] input: Razer Kiyo Pro as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/input/input38
[  233.076954] usb 2-1: current rate 16000 is different from the runtime rate 24000
[  233.078675] usb 2-1: current rate 16000 is different from the runtime rate 32000
[  233.683972] usb 2-1: current rate 16000 is different from the runtime rate 48000
[  235.015361] usb 2-1: current rate 16000 is different from the runtime rate 48000
[  235.621541] usb 2-1: current rate 16000 is different from the runtime rate 48000
[  236.329730] usb 2-1: current rate 16000 is different from the runtime rate 48000
[  430.669902] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  436.241633] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  441.617556] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  441.825686] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 3, error -62
[  447.249525] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  452.625409] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[  452.833422] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 4, error -62
[  452.841384] usb usb2-port1: attempt power cycle
[  453.776288] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  453.988287] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  454.193359] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 5, error -71
[  454.404406] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  454.615899] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  454.821370] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 6, error -71
[  454.829394] usb usb2-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

The message "USB disconnect, device number 2" appears when I run `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`. The other messages appear in quick succession without my intervention.

`v4l2-ctl --list-devices` output:

```
❯ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Razer Kiyo Pro (usb-0000:00:14.0-1):
    /dev/video3

HP HD Camera: HP HD Camera (usb-0000:00:14.0-2):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
```

Razer Kiyo Pro is only listed in the output first time I run the command. On subsequent runs only the HP HD Camera is listed (this is the built-in laptop camera).

Can anyone please advise what I can do to make the webcam work on my laptop? I have spent some time googling the error messages, specifically "Failed to set UVC probe control" and "device not accepting address", but I haven't found on a working solution yet.

UPD1: I installed Windows 10 in the VM and passed the webcam through to the VM, then I stopped the VM and the camera started working in Linux (on the host) too. But after some time it stops working, and all my USB devices disconnect and don't work until I reboot the laptop:

```
[ 7061.230704] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command.
[ 7061.230709] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: USBSTS:\x9c\xff\xff\xc0M
[ 7061.230716] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
[ 7061.230727] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 7061.230739] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: HC died; cleaning up
[ 7061.230765] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 7061.286939] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 7061.286944] usb 1-6.2: USB disconnect, device number 7
[ 7061.286945] usb 1-6.2.1: USB disconnect, device number 8
[ 7061.286947] usb 1-6.2.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 11
[ 7061.536274] usb 1-6.2.2: USB disconnect, device number 9
[ 7061.587552] usb 1-6.2.3: USB disconnect, device number 10
[ 7061.646762] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 8, error -108
[ 7061.646843] usb usb2-port1: couldn't allocate usb_device
[ 7061.720337] usb 1-6.5: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 7061.721357] usb 1-7: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 7061.721764] usb 1-10: USB disconnect, device number 6
```

The camera is connected to `usb2-port1`.

Comment: Have you tried the firmware update?

Comment: @soyer I have tried to update the camera firmware, but I have not been able to complete the process. The firmware update tool tells me to contact Razer support. Razer support discarded my support request. I am not sure how to proceed. I am able to use the camera for a couple of minutes until the "xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command." message appears.

Comment: Is it a new notebook? It can be a xhci usb driver bug too. Could you try with a newer OS, like 22.04?

Comment: @soyer The notebook is not new, I had it for a couple of years already, but I always had issues with cameras so I kept using the built-in camera. I tried 22.04, Fedora 35 and Fedora 36 beta live CDs on this laptop, on another PC, and in a virtual machine;  Razer Kiyo Pro behaves the same on all systems except Windows 10. I suppose this could be caused either by a xhci usb driver, or by the camera itself (but the windows driver has a workaround for the camera issue).

Comment: Do you have the newest BIOS?

Comment: @soyer I updated BIOS on the laptop to the newest version after your comment. The issue persists with the newest BIOS.